# How can i send specific cookie name of visitors from my wordpress website to google analytics with a custom dimension variable?

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

Can I send cookie value data of a specific cookie of visitors from my WordPress website to google analytics? I'm thinking of creating a data layer in google tag manager and send it to google analytics via a custom dimension.

any thoughts on how to do it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Technically you can do it as you described. In GTM, with a variable 1st cookie you retrieve the value from the cookie and use it as the value of a custom dimension in the Google Analytics tag. You have to use the same index of that custom dimension has in the Analytics Property (where you have to configured it before).

Comment: Thanks!
I'm now looking for a script that can pull the cookie data from my website.
Any remarks on how to do it will help!